# Xcode Build Error - CodeSign

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I am trying to test my iOS application on my iPhone. I keep getting the same error.

```
/Users/usrname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Navigation-abxszioyejjvsqfxzhvoyunubgef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app: replacing invalid existing signature
/Users/usrname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Navigation-abxszioyejjvsqfxzhvoyunubgef/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

-My provisioning profile and signing requests are good and valid.
-All certs/profiles/devices/App IDs are good and valid. 
-I have tried deleting and re-creating the certs several times with no luck. 
-The certs are set to use System Defaults instead of Always Trust
-My App ID is set to a xCode wildcard 123456.*
-I have set my Bundle Indentifer to justsometext, as from what I read in the docs, this  doesnt matter because of the wildcard.

Can somebody please help me before I rip my hair out. Thanks!

I am using the latest version of Xcode and latest iOS on iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you correctly set the "Trust" section of Apple's WDRC certificate?

http://natelyman.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=105:what-is-cssmerrtpnottrusted&catid=39:iphone-sdk

Comment: Technically yes. It says that it should have a green circle with a check, and that the trust settings should be set to Use System Defaults. I have it set to that, however it still has a blue circle with a plus sign ???? How do I get the green circle with the check mark?

Comment: Is it possible there is some other reason why the certificate would say that it has custom trust settings, even though it is set to default?

Comment: Have you checked _all_ the trust settings for this certificate? Maybe something is set differently?

Comment: It was the trust settings. After deleting the certificate several times from all installed locations, then re-installing it, it finally worked.